# Unable to locate the model you have specified: modelName

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load this model:

```
class Menu {

    function show_menu()
    {
        $obj =& get_instance();
        $obj->load->helper('url');
        $menu = anchor("start/hello/fred","Say hello to Fred |");
        $menu .= anchor("start/hello/bert","Say hello to Bert |");
        $menu .= anchor("start/another_function","Do something else |");
        return $menu;
    }

}
```

This is where my controller is:

```
function hello($name)
{
    $this->load->model('Menu');  
    $mymenu  = $this->Menu->show_menu();
}
```

Why do I get this error?

`Unable to locate the model you have specified: menu`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeIgniter can't find the file of the model. If you named your model `Menu`, make sure the file name is `menu.php` and not something else like `menu_model.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the the model name is Menu and the class name is also Menu

```
class Menu extends CI_Model{

    function show_menu()
    {
        $obj =& get_instance();
        $obj->load->helper('url');
        $menu = anchor("start/hello/fred","Say hello to Fred |");
        $menu .= anchor("start/hello/bert","Say hello to Bert |");
        $menu .= anchor("start/another_function","Do something else |");
        return $menu;
    }

}
```

but loading the class is 'menu' NOT 'Menu'

```
function hello($name)
{
    $this->load->model('menu');  
    $mymenu  = $this->menu->show_menu();
}
```

hope this was helpful